# AngularJS nested ui-view into an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-router

I'm creating an app using Spotify API.
This app can:
1. find albums by artist name through an input field
2. once the albums are shown, the user can click the album's title and see its tracks

I have created 2 views: 
1. the albums view 
2. the tracks view, child of albums view.

I'd like to show the tracks ui-view of a specific clicked album - with its ID - into the albums' ng-repeat, but the result is that I have the same tracks list of the clicked album throughout all albums list. How can I show the album's track ui-view into the clicked album container that is a result of an ng-repeat directive?

Here's the code.

Routing:

```
------
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      .state('albums', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      }).
      state('albums.tracks', {
        url: ':id/tracks',
        templateUrl: 'views/tracks.html',
        controller: 'TracksCtrl'
      });
})
-----
```

The albums view:

```
<div ng-if="albums.items">
    <h1>{{searchedArtist}}'s Album List:</h1>
    <!-- albums ng-repeat -->
    <div ng-repeat="album in albums.items | unique:'name'" id="{{album.id}}">
    <img  ng-src="{{album.images[1].url}}" width="100">
    <!-- the action to translate the state to tracks view -->
    <a ui-sref="albums.tracks({id : album.id})">{{album.name}}</a>
    <!-- tracks view -->
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Main albums controller:

```
angular.module('spotifyAngularApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, spotifyService) {

  var options = {
    'limit': 10
  };

  $scope.searchAlbums= function () {
    var sanitizeArtist = $scope.artist.split(' ').join('+');
    $scope.searchedArtist = $scope.artist;

    spotifyService.search(sanitizeArtist, 'album', options).then(function(data) {
        $scope.albums = data.albums;
    });
  };
});
```

The tracks controller:

```
angular.module('spotifyAngularApp')
.controller('TracksCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, spotifyService) {
    console.log($stateParams);
    spotifyService.albumTracks($stateParams.id).then(function(data){
        $scope.tracks = data.items;
      });
});
```

Comment: Maybe this could be intersting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24902144/1679310. There is an example how to handle scenario with repeat... maybe that could give some ideas...

Comment: Thank you for your reference, it works, but when you instace a new state the ui-router looks for a template url and an ui-view. but i was trying to figure out how to add in an ng-repeat a ui-view with another ng-repeat inside.

Comment: can  u create plunkr , where have you reached with sample data it would be more helpfull

Comment: If the reason is just to separate tracks views' logic from albums controller. Just use ng-include with ng-controller for tracks views' template and controller. And also if you want to show tracks for a specific album when the page loads (e.g. according to url parameters) you can handle this showing/hiding logic in your albums controller.

Answer (score 11):

What you're trying to do does not make sense. A state may have multiple views associated with it but these views must be **predefined**, not **dynamically generated**.

There is a conflict between the code where you **statically** define your **only 1 view**:

```
state('albums.tracks', {
        url: ':id/tracks',
        templateUrl: 'views/tracks.html',
        controller: 'TracksCtrl'
      });
```

and the code where you **generate ui-view dynamically** with `ng-repeat`. There is no logic to say which `ui-view` to load your html into. In this case, I suggest to have only 1 `ui-view` by moving it out of `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-if="albums.items">
    <h1>{{searchedArtist}}'s Album List:</h1>
    <!-- albums ng-repeat -->
    <div ng-repeat="album in albums.items | unique:'name'" id="{{album.id}}">
        <img  ng-src="{{album.images[1].url}}" width="100">
        <!-- the action to translate the state to tracks view -->
        <a ui-sref="albums.tracks({id : album.id})">{{album.name}}</a>
    </div
    <!-- tracks view -->
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Or if you really need to put it inside `ng-repeat` due to the way you layout your page, try `ng-if` to ensure that only 1 `ui-view` is shown. `(this is a workaround and not recommended)`

```
<div ng-if="albums.items">
        <h1>{{searchedArtist}}'s Album List:</h1>
        <!-- albums ng-repeat -->
        <div ng-repeat="album in albums.items | unique:'name'" id="{{album.id}}">
            <img  ng-src="{{album.images[1].url}}" width="100">
            <!-- the action to translate the state to tracks view -->
            <a ui-sref="albums.tracks({id : album.id})">{{album.name}}</a>
            <!-- tracks view -->
            <div ng-if="$state.is('albums.tracks',{id : album.id})" ui-view></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and modify your `MainCtrl` a bit to inject `$state` so that we have access to it in the view:

```
angular.module('spotifyAngularApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, spotifyService, $state) {
  $scope.$state = $state;

  //your code
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do doesn't really make sense. What you're saying with this is "repeat this state's (albums') view a number of times equal to how many items there are in the collection albums." But then, when you click on the anchor, you're telling the album.tracks *state* to go get the album with the id of the album you clicked on. This will then display the album.tracks state in every ui-view in the albums view (which is what you're seeing).

A single state can't be "instanced" multiple times on the same page like you're attempting to do here. See this question for more information: [Does Angular JS support routing of multiple views on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404730/does-angular-js-support-routing-of-multiple-views-on-the-same-page)

I would suggest building this a different way - perhaps using an ng-repeat with ngInclude inside, if you need to keep your template separate. Otherwise, it's probably just easier to build the whole template on one page, ng-repeat for all of the albums and tracks, then hide all of them and show each one when clicked via ngHide/ngShow.

Comment: The `ngInclude` directive is definitely the route to go here, and encapsulate the potential "views" as a collection within the controller that can then serve up the content as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to create multiple views inside an ng-repeat, would it be better to create a directive?