# AngularJS Splitted views

Tags: angularjs, nested, view

I'm really new to AngularJS and I started to make a learning Project and I came to a point where I do not know how to proceed. Behind AngularJS Frontend there is an API which retrieves database data(Like menu elements, product list).

Than I would like to split my template in 2 parts and each should be handled by different Angular Models. What I'm trying it doesn't seems to work. What is the correct way to do this?

```
-index.html

<head></head>
<body ng-app="appApp">
        <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
</body>

--views/main.html

<div ng-include src="navigation.html"></div>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1></h1>
  <p class="lead"></p>
  <p></p>
</div>

<div class="row products">
    <div ng-include src="product_list.html"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>footer</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19005224/617996).

Comment: product_list.html and navigation.html

does both of them have there own set of controllers defined?

try enclosing the names in single codes i.e.

<div ng-include src="'product_list.html'"></div>

Comment: okay can you explain why needs to be enclosed like that? It works like that